# blank page when extending template page

Tags: django

I get blank page when i am trying to extend the polls/index page to my main blog/index page. Whay i am getting that ?

blog/index.html

```
  {% extends "polls/index.html" %}   
    <!doctype "html5">
    <html>
    <head>
    .....
   {% block poll %}{% endblock %}
```

polls/index.html

```
{% block poll %}
    {% if latest_poll_list %}
        <ul>
            {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`extends` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#extends) should be used in child template, not in base(parent) template.

---

blog/index.html

```
<!doctype "html5">
<html>
<head>
.....
{% block poll %}{% endblock %}
```

---

polls/index.html

```
{% extends "blog/index.html" %}    {# <--- #}
{% block poll %}
    {% if latest_poll_list %}
        <ul>
            {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

See [Template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#template-inheritance).

Comment: ok, i implemented on poll/index.html `{% extends "blog/index.html" %}` , but it doesnt implement anything, now i can see the page, but polls model isnt there

Comment: @EriksJauga, Check whether you passed `latest_poll_list` correctly. (By putting `latest_poll_list: {{ latest_poll_list }}` before `if ...`).

Comment: i rly dont have a clue what should i do now. It doesnt include anything on my main blog/index.html , justi n /posts/ it adds style and a news not found, what i dont need...

Answer (score 1):

**Block tag {% block NAMEOFBLOCKTAG %}:**

Defines a block that can be overridden by child templates. So, this tag is present in the parent template as well as the child templates. In parent template, we close the tag immediately after we open it as:

**in parent template** `{% block NAME_OF_BLOCKTAG %}{% endNAME_OF_BLOCKTAG %}`

In child templates, the block tag is opened and the elements to represent inside that tag are written before the tag is closed.

**in child template**

```
{% block NAME_OF_BLOCKTAG %} 
# some elements from child template
{% endNAME_OF_BLOCKTAG %}
```

**Extend tag {% extends NAME_OF_PARENT_TEMPLETE %}**

Signals that this template extends a parent template. Used in child template at the top of the file.

**Use it like this in your case:**

```
#blog/index.html
<!doctype "html5">
<html>
<head>
.....
{% block poll %}{% endblock %}
```

and

```
#polls/index.html
{% extends "blog/index.html" %}
{% block poll %}
    {% if latest_poll_list %}
        <ul>
            {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: but in blog/index.html i dont see polls template. it doesnt implement anything. Just in polls/index.html i see new thing no news created. whay?